# How do I hide "Chapter 0" in this custom style when using a numberless chapter?

Tags: formatting, conditionals, chapters, titlesec

Everything works perfect when I use `\chapter{chaptername}`, but I noticed that my table of contents and other similar non-numbered chapters have a "Chapter 0" in my header.

```
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\sffamily\Huge\scshape}
  {}{0pt}
  {\thispagestyle{empty}    % Remove page number on new chapters
  \setcounter{definition}{0} % Reset Definition Counter  
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=cyan] (0,-1) rectangle
          (25cm,3cm);
        \draw[fill=cyan] (0,-24) rectangle
          (25cm,-25cm);
        \node[anchor=west,xshift=.21\paperwidth,yshift=-.01\paperheight,rectangle]
              {\color{white}\LARGE CHAPTER \Huge\thechapter};
        \node[anchor=west,xshift=.21\paperwidth,yshift=-.065\paperheight,rectangle]
              {\color{cyan}\Huge\MakeUppercase{#1}};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
```

I looked it up briefly, but I can't seem to make sense of how to use conditionals to determine certain things.

Comment: Try to put the code inside `{\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@   }`

Comment: @Sigur With that, I get errors "Missing number, treated as zero"

Comment: I believe that you have to use `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` and put your code inside it since the if contains `@`.

Comment: Same problem, sadly.

Comment: For future reference, rather than submitted code snippets, it's best to provide complete, [minimal working examples (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) of what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) sets `\ttl@labelfalse` if you call `\chapter*` (and true otherwise). You can use this to condition on inserting a node containing the chapter heading:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec
\usepackage{tikz}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf
\makeatletter
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\sffamily\Huge\scshape}
  {}{0pt}
  {\thispagestyle{empty}    % Remove page number on new chapters
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=cyan] (0,-1) rectangle
          (25cm,3cm);
        \draw[fill=cyan] (0,-24) rectangle
          (25cm,-25cm);
        \ifttl@label% <---------------------- Added condition on \ifttl@label
          \node[anchor=west,xshift=.21\paperwidth,yshift=-.01\paperheight,rectangle]
              {\color{white}\LARGE CHAPTER \Huge\thechapter};
        \fi% <------------------------------- end condition on \ifttl@label
        \node[anchor=west,xshift=.21\paperwidth,yshift=-.065\paperheight,rectangle]
              {\color{cyan}\Huge\MakeUppercase{#1}};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A numbered chapter}
\chapter*{An unnumbered chapter}
\end{document}
```

Note the positioning of `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` (outside the definition of `\titleformat`).